# Is it possible Sync Android app with Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have read the GCM detail from Google [WebSite](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) and watched the [Google IO Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YoaP6hcDctM).

But in the Video and GCM Documentation there is example GCM Send one same message to multiple android devices. But in my app I don't want to send the same message to multiple android device.

**For Example**

I have two android devices with different google account and I want to Sync Notes in app with GCM.

1. First device register with one@gmail.com
2. Second device register with two@gmail.com

First device have different Notes. and 
Second device have different Notes

If I update notes on server for first device. I want it will Sync with first device(one@gmail.com) not with Second device(two@gmail.com)

Is it possible with the GCM.....? please Let me know.

Thank you

Comment: your server have to make a call to GCM API with the a list of users you wanna notify, in your case just <one@gmail.com> and once you receive message from GCM you need the your application to update notes on phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, each instance of you application running on each device will have a unique registration id

> Registration ID: An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android
>   application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android
>   application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party
>   application server, which uses it to identify each device that has
>   registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In
>   other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android
>   application running on a particular device.

When your application on a particular devices registers for GCM, it receives a unique registration ID. This registration ID is received after the GCM registration is successful. You can use this registration id (unique to one@gmail.com and one particular device) to send the message to that app+device combo only.

> A 3rd-party application server can either send messages to a single
>   device or to multiple devices. A message sent to multiple devices
>   simultaneously is called a multicast message.

For example

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyB-1uEai2WiUapxCs2Q0GZYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx..."],
  "data" : {
    ...
  },
}
```

the above code sends the message to one instance of your app running on a particular device